# Node Express pointing my stylesheet, plugins and javascript to the current url

Tags: css, node.js, handlebars.js

I have handlebars bootstrap pages that I would like to use which have stylesheet, plugins and javascript pointing to `public/assets/..` ;

```
<link href="assets/css/my-custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I have declared static files

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

and

```
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('page-register', {title: 'Register'}); 
});
```

However, when I load the /register , the stylesheet etc looks for

```
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/register/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

What do I have to do to set the get

```
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Comment: did you write `app.use('/register', router);` ?

Comment: Because there are lots of pages and lost of href with the same style, I wonder if I can use like app.use() to simplify rather than changging it one by one in the pages itself.

I have tried using app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname +'public'))); and app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: No, I did not and it's giving me error to use app.use('/register', router);

Answer (score 0):

You need that / before assets : `<link href="/assets...>`

Comment: I am aware of that, and fyi I am using bootstrap pages which use <link href="assets...> , because there are lots of pages without '/' then I am looking for another solution without editing the href in every pages.